# jquery Ajax error function is not triggered

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my function (1st Code piece), when I run below function, it goes into to my code through my handler and in my code it throws exception (2nd Code piece), after exception is catched, it goes back to my handler and get's inside the catch area, and finally turns back to javascript success function, but error it doesn't run the error part.

```
    BenefitOperations.performBenefitOperation = function(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "BenefitOperation.axd",
        data: JSON.stringify(data.BenefitOperationJson),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function() { PageMask.show(); },
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.Success == true)
            performPostBack();
          else
            window.alert(Res.BenefitOperationFailure);
    },
    error: function(e, x, y) { window.alert(Res.BenefitOperationError + y); }   }); }
```

This is my function

```
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Benefit operation type {0} for benefit type {1} is not registered", Enum.GetName(typeof(EmployeeBenefitData.BenefitOperationType), parameters.OperationTypeID), Enum.GetName(typeof(EmployeeBenefitData.BenefitTypeEnum), parameters.BenefitTypeID)));
    }
```

this is my handler's catch

```
    catch
    {

        jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Success = false
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(jsonOutput);
    }
```

Comment: what is value of response.Success in success?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `error` callback of `$.ajax()` doesn't get called in your code because there is no error. `error` means there was an issue retrieving the response, eg. a 500 error from the server.

In your code you're catching the `ApplicationException` yourself and returning JSON. If you'd prefer to use the `error` handler, raise the exception and don't catch it in your C# code - however it should be noted your current code is a better method.

Comment: I modified my code and inside the catch, I throw an exception and now I am able to enter the "error" part of the javascript, but I tried to display error with e.responseText (I saw that somewhere else), but it displayed the whole html of the page, how can I just display the e.Message in my exception ?

Comment: @HOY the HTML you received is the source of the YSOD error page. You would need to find the element containing the error and get its text. As I said though, this is not a good idea. A better way would be to keep your current catch, and return JSON something like `{ success: false, errorMessage: e.Message }` and then in your `success` handler check for the `success` property and deal with it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Rory is right, 
just set HTTP  500 status code when you hit error / Exception or operation faild.

you can set HTTP 500 status code like...

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```